# How to fetch data from XML file into combo-boxes using javascript based on DOM API

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, combobox

I have XML file with name "mobiles.xml"; The XML file looks like;

```
<mobiles>

<brand name="Nokia">
<model>Lumia 720</model>
<price>Rs. 27,600</price>

<model>Lumia 510</model>
<price>Rs. 15,300</price>

<model>Asha 303</model>
<price>Rs. 12,900</price>

<model>X2 05</model>
<price>Rs. 5,550</price>
</brand>

<brand name="Samsung">
<model>Galaxy Mega 5.8</model>
<price>Rs. 42,000</price>

<model>S5610</model>
<price>Rs. 10,000</price>

<model>E1207</model>
<price>Rs. 2,000</price>

<model>E1205</model>
<price>Rs. 1,700</price>
</brand>

<brand name="Sony">
<model>Xperia ZL</model>
<price>48,000</price>

<model>Xperia J</model>
<price>Rs. 18,000</price>

<model>Xperia miro</model>
<price>Rs. 16,000</price>

<model>Xperia Tipo Dual</model>
<price>Rs. 12,000</price>
</brand>

</mobiles>
```

Actually I want to retrieve data from XML file through javascript which is DOM based (node based) but I don't know how to do it. I want to retrieve data from XML file into combo-boxes (dropdown lists)... For example, I have to fetch the data of "brand" from XML file in combo-box. When i select the particular brand the values of "models" should be loaded from XML file into another combo-box. Now I have 3rd element price in XML File. I want to display the price in textbox of a particular mobile based on selected values of combo-boxes "Brand" & "Models" after hitting Submit button. How will i do this? Please don't use built-in functions. I want to learn how to do it based on DOM API and Javascript. It will be nice if you people also tell me how to add and save data of new brands, their models and price through textboxes into XML file?

Answer (score 0):

I have fetch the data in 2 combo-boxes from XML file and code looks like;

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript">
/* Cross-Browser Import of XML document into a XML Document. */
function importXML(xmlfile) {
var xmlDoc;
if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != 'undefined') {
//code for IE
xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async = false;
xmlDoc.load(xmlfile);
} else {
try {
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", xmlfile, false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
} 
catch (Exception) {
alert("Your browser is not supported. Try firefox !!");
}
}
return xmlDoc;
}
/* Get the options for the model combobox from the XML. */
function loadXMLOption() {
// Load the xml file
var xmlDoc=importXML("mobiles.xml");
xmlObj=xmlDoc.documentElement;
// Get all Elements with Tag name 'brand'
BrandObj = xmlObj.getElementsByTagName("brand");
for(var i=0; i < BrandObj.length; i++) {
// Loop through each brand tag and check if its name is equal to the selected brand value
if (document.getElementById('Company').value == BrandObj[i].getAttribute("name")) {  
// If matching brand found get the model tags under that brand
modelObj = BrandObj[i].getElementsByTagName("model");
document.getElementById('Model').options.length = 0;
// Create options for the Model comboBox.
for(var j=0; j < modelObj.length; j++) {
var opt = document.createElement('option');
opt.value = modelObj[j].firstChild.nodeValue;
opt.text = modelObj[j].firstChild.nodeValue;
document.getElementById('Model').options.add(opt);      }     }     } }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Chained Drop-Down - using XML</h2>
Brand : <select id="Company" onchange="loadXMLOption();">
<option value=""></option> 
<option value="Nokia">Nokia</option>
<option value="Samsung">Samsung</option> 
<option value="Sony">Sony</option>
</select>
Model : <select id="Model"> </select>
</body></html>
```

Now I want to get the value of price against particular item selected in comboboxes in textbox. How will I do it?